# string changes after posting array data in php ci

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter, post

i wanna post an array data in php codeigniter.
this is a part of my code in view

```
 <input type="hidden" name="category[<?php echo $i; ?>]"
  value="<?php echo $info['category']; ?>  ">
 <?php var_dump($info['category']);?>
```

the result of above var_dump shows the correct string.
for example:

> string(7) "parquet"

but when i post the data to controller string changes and var_dump() result is:

> string(9) "parquet "

my question is what's happening when i post data and how can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have two `space` characters in your value before you end the quote.

```
value="<?php echo $info['category']; ?>  ">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
<input type="hidden" name="category[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $info['category']; ?>">
<?php var_dump($info['category']);?>
```